# Codename one Bar Charts

Tags: codenameone

I have created the bar charts and all looks good but the datas are movable that leads to misalignment . How to solve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `chart.setPanEnabled(false);` to disable panning. You might want to also disable pinch to zoom with `chart.setZoomEnabled(false);`.